# Register a property editor for a record in Delphi

Tags: delphi, properties, editor, components

I write a component where a published property is a record.
Ex.

```
type
  TRecordProperty = record
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
 end;

 TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
 private
   FMyRecord: TRecordProperty;
 published       
   property MyRecord: TRecordProperty read FMyRecord write FMyRecord;
 end;
```

Well, in object explorer isn´t visible MyRecord property.
In Procedure register must I declare an editor? How do it?

Comment: Yes, of course you have to write your own property editor; the IDE knows nothing about `TRecordProperty` or how to edit it. Why would it?  The Delphi source comes with examples of many types of property editors in the `source\Property Editors` folder. Maybe the better question I could ask is *why do you need a record-type property to begin with?*. What built-in Delphi component has a record-type property?

Comment: Isn't this documented?

Comment: Please do some research first http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor

Comment: And what about this solution : a property per record fields?

Comment: I need a record property for retain name, mac address and ip address obtained from windows, I not need any editor, only some as....
`MyRecord [+]`
 `              a`
`               b`
`               c`
In object explorer, each one listed under another

Comment: a bit late answer: use TPersistent class instead of record, that will be seen exactly as you wish.